# $\arctan {x}$, for nonnegative integer $x$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Show that for nonnegative integers $a,b,c,d$, where $a<b<c<d$.
$$\arctan{b}+\arctan{c} < \arctan{a}+\arctan{d}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is not true.  Consider $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=99$, and $d=100$.  Then

$$\arctan b-\arctan a=\int_1^2{dx\over1+x^2}\gt{1\over5}$$

while

$$\arctan d-\arctan c=\int_{99}^{100}{dx\over1+x^2}\lt{1\over1+99^2}\lt{1\over5}$$

so

$$\arctan d-\arctan c\lt\arctan b-\arctan a$$

for these integers, i.e., $\arctan 1+\arctan 100\lt\arctan 2+\arctan99$.